# cordova cant create folder windows

Tags: cordova, windows-10, visual-studio-cordova

When I try to create a media folder inside the presistent folder of a windows 10 cordova app I'm getting the following error when debugging with Visual Studio in the JavaScript console:

```
Exception is about to be caught by JavaScript library code at line 314, column 13 in ms-appx-web://appname/www/cordova.js 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'error' of undefined or null reference
```

The code I used to create a folder is the following:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
    //success
    var directoryEntry = fileSystem.root; // to get root path of directory
    //create directory
    directoryEntry.getDirectory("media", { create: true, exclusive: false }, function(parent) {
              //directory created successfully
                console.log("/media created");
            }, function(parent) {
              //failed to create directory
                console.log('no folder created');
            }); });
```

Comment: I made a basic demo, but didn't reproduce the problem. Could you please try it in an empty blank project? If the problem persists, maybe share it through Github or other online repo.